# Chain rule for variational derivatives and differentiation of an integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

Assume that I have the following functional:
$$
F[u_1,u_2,...u_N,\nabla u_1,...,\nabla u_N,...;t]=\int_{\Omega} f( u_1(x,t),u_2(x,t),...,u_N(x,t),\nabla u_1 , \nabla u_2,...   ) dV
$$
where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ . Is it true that:
$$
\frac{dF}{dt}= \int_{\Omega} \Sigma_{i=1}^N \frac{\delta F}{\delta u_i } \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t} 
$$ 
?
If so, will you please explain why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Presumably you mean $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: fixed it . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically the chain rule. The problem is how you move the derivative into the integration, i.e., why
$$
\frac{dF}{dt}=\int\frac{df}{dt}
$$
hold.

There are different ways to justify the above equation. You may put $f\in L^\infty$ or $\Omega$ is bounded and $f$ is uniformly conts. I would suggest you to read page 454 about this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849743) to get more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **with appropriate hypotheses** (on $f$ and/or on $\Omega$), one can pass the derivative inside the integral, and so the second identity follows from
$$
\frac{d}{dt}f( u_1(x,t),u_2(x,t),...,u_N(x,t) )=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_i}( u_1(x,t),u_2(x,t),...,u_N(x,t) )\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t}(x,t).
$$
This property is usually called **Leibniz's rule** .

Comment: Jonas, thanks, but I specifically mean for variational derivatives. For example, if $f$ is also a function of $\nabla u _1 $ , is it true to pass to variational derivatives and not $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_i}$? Thanks

Comment: I see. Well, you did write $F[t]$ which as it is should be interpreted as $F(t)$ (you wrote no functions). As it is, it would be what is in my answer. :) I would suggest clarifying the question first.

Comment: Fixed it. I hope I made myself clear now. Thanks a lot anyway... Hope you will still be able to help